# rpm error: Failed dependencies:ReviewBoard

Tags: review-board

We need to install  the review board rpm package on Rhel 5 32 bit machine. We couldnt install the package because of the below error

```
$# - rpm -ivh ReviewBoard-1.6.4-1.fc18.noarch.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
        django-evolution >= 0.6.5 is needed by ReviewBoard-1.6.4-1.fc18.noarch
        python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by ReviewBoard-1.6.4-1.fc18.noarch
        python-djblets >= 0.6.16 is needed by ReviewBoard-1.6.4-1.fc18.noarch
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by ReviewBoard-1.6.4-1.fc18.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by ReviewBoard-1.6.4-1.fc18.noarch
```

Kindly help me to get the proper RPM for the above dependencies

Comment: Your question has many issues (title, subject, format, ...). Please carefully read the [help]. Your question is very likely to be closed.

Comment: Changed the title , subject and Format